# Google Place API gives non-English results

Tags: api, maps, google-places-api

Using the Google Place Details API to get the address through an place_id.
You can specify the language=en but for example a hotel in Phuket will still return the city and province in there local language.

This is a sample output of the Google Places API:

```
[result] => Array
    (
        [address_components] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [long_name] => ภูเก็ต
                        [short_name] => จ.ภูเก็ต
```

Long_name and short_name both contain the local version in their own script. My users would like to see the international version of that city name, like "Phuket"
Example place: Phuket Marriott Resort & Spa, Merlin Beach, Pa Tong, Kathu District, Phuket, Thailand

Why would Google not supply the English version? On their Google Maps they display the full address.

They give a full address in the API adr_address but you would have to parse that yourself quite unreliable.

You could also use Google Translate for a translation but would be unreliable as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you give us your code, your API call, which langage you use, etc ... ?

Comment: Thanks!
The language here used is PHP, but I tried it briefly in Javascript and the same results.

I make a call to:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json
  with the place_id , (+ a non relevant token+api key) and language=en and region but that does not seem to change anything.

Comment: If i want to test,  need the place ID you use

Comment: For me it works, long name have Phuket, can you give me your request without your api key please

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is the placeid: ChIJ29BYbjIlUDARL2zUokhvDmg

Array
(
    [placeid] => ChIJ29BYbjIlUDARL2zUokhvDmg
    [language] => en
    [region] => US
)

Comment: (I first search for 'Phuket Marriott Resort & Spa, Merlin Beach' to get the place_id towards this api: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json )

Answer (score 0):

I tested it, the result isn't in  `"address_components"` , you will find the adress here :

```
"formatted_address" : "99 Muen-Ngoen Road Tri-Trang Beach, Patong Patong Phuket, ตำบลป่าตอง อำเภอกะทู้ ภูเก็ต 83150, Thailand"
```

The full JSON reuslt :

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "ภูเก็ต",
            "short_name" : "จ.ภูเก็ต",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "ตำบลป่าตอง",
            "short_name" : "ตำบลป่าตอง",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "อำเภอกะทู้",
            "short_name" : "อำเภอกะทู้",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Thailand",
            "short_name" : "TH",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "83150",
            "short_name" : "83150",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "99 Muen-Ngoen Road Tri-Trang Beach, Patong Patong Phuket, \u003cspan class=\"extended-address\"\u003eตำบลป่าตอง\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eอำเภอกะทู้\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eภูเก็ต\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e83150\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eThailand\u003c/span\u003e",
      "business_status" : "OPERATIONAL",
      "formatted_address" : "99 Muen-Ngoen Road Tri-Trang Beach, Patong Patong Phuket, ตำบลป่าตอง อำเภอกะทู้ ภูเก็ต 83150, Thailand",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "076 335 300",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 7.883537999999999,
            "lng" : 98.27270779999999
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 7.884994980291502,
               "lng" : 98.27402173029151
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 7.882297019708498,
               "lng" : 98.27132376970849
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
      "id" : "47f504a09fb6891f688957af609c39a4064b150e",
      "international_phone_number" : "+66 76 335 300",
      "name" : "Phuket Marriott Resort & Spa, Merlin Beach",
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : true,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "0000"
               }
            }
         ],
         "weekday_text" : [
            "Monday: Open 24 hours",
            "Tuesday: Open 24 hours",
            "Wednesday: Open 24 hours",
            "Thursday: Open 24 hours",
            "Friday: Open 24 hours",
            "Saturday: Open 24 hours",
            "Sunday: Open 24 hours"
         ]
      },
```

Comment: Thanks! So it looks like its impossible to get the City (Phuket) or province in English characters? In the formatted_address there is no city or province mentioned in English?

Google just does not support the English names?

Comment: For google, the city is Patong Patong Phuket, so it will be really hard to just have Phuket :S, dont forget to valid the answer if it resolve your question ;)